# Jquery not working in dynamically generated form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cross-domain

I am generating a form in `www.sitetwo.com` by using some scripts called from `www.siteone.com`. As I have to submit the form in `www.sitetwo.com` to `www.siteone.com`, I am using Ajax using JSONP method. But, the generated form is not supporting any scripts.
My code is here:

```
   //script in www.sitetwo.com
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        "use strict";
        function js(n) {
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            s.setAttribute("src", n);
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
        }
        js("http://www.siteone.com/script.js");
    };
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $=jQuery.noConflict();
    $(".submitbutton").hover(function(){
      alert("hai");
    }
    </script>
    <div id="newform">
    </div>
```

The form that is dynamically rendered in div with id newform is as follows:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="go" class="submitbutton">
</form>
```

I tried applying basic script of on hover alert.But it isn't working. cannot we use directly scripts like this for dynamically generated forms. If so how can we overcome this problem. I  have searched for errors in browser. No error is shown. What can be the solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".submitbutton").hover(function(){
      alert("hai");
    }
```

change in

```
$(".submitbutton").on("hover",function(){
      alert("hai");
    }
```

reference [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 2):

You are generating the form dynamically, to apply some events to the dynamic element you have to use `.on()`, other thing is to change the event to `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` instead of `hover`

try this:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.submitbutton', function(){
  alert("hai");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use hover in that case, need to use delegated event handlers using events [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave)

[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is not a event, it is a helper method to register mouseenter and mouseleave event handlers

> Bind two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the
>   mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.submitbutton', function(){
  alert("hai");
}
```