# jQuery autocomplete failing after dynamically adding additional text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, autocomplete

** UPDATE ** I changed the HTML id's to classes. And incorporated the advice in the current top answer. The autocomplete now works but the autocomplete option list DOES NOT successfully display for the dynamically adde text input field. It works for the original though.

I have added the updated code below.

I just added jQuery UI autocomplete to a form in my Rails app. The feature works fine however it doesn't work when I dynamically add another input field with the same class?

```
<a href="#" class="addNewIngredient">Add ingredient</a>
```

After dynamically adding an additional field, the original field's autocomplete feature continues to work without any issues but the newly added field's autocomplete feature does not work.

Why would the autocomplete feature fail for the dynamically added field if the input fields all share the same id?

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".addNewIngredient").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
$(".ingredientField").append($("#new_ingredients_form").html());
$(".select_ingredient").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: '/ingredients',
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $('.select_ingredient').val(ui.item.name);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('.select_ingredient').val(ui.item.name);
    $('.link_ingredient_id').val(ui.item.id);
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.name + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
});

$(".removeIngredient").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
$(".ingredientField #new_ingredients_form").empty();
});
});
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>Create Meal</h1>
<%= form_for(@meal) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br/>

  <div class="ingredientField">
    <%= render "ingredient_form" %>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="addNewIngredient">Add ingredient</a>
  <a href="#" class="removeIngredient">Remove ingredient</a>

  <%= f.label :clean_up %>
  <%= f.select :clean_up, options_for_select([["", ""],["Low", "low"], ["Med", "med"], ["High", "high"]]) %><br/>

  <%= f.label :homemade %>
  <%= f.select :homemade, options_for_select([["Yes", true],["No", false]])  %><br/>

  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

**_ingredient_form.html.erb**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
 // Below is the name of the textfield that will be autocomplete
    $('.select_ingredient').autocomplete({
 // This shows the min length of charcters that must be typed before the autocomplete looks for a match.
            minLength: 2,
 // This is the source of the auocomplete suggestions. In this case a list of names from the people controller, in JSON format.
            source: '<%= ingredients_path(:json) %>',
  // This updates the textfield when you move the updown the suggestions list, with your keyboard. In our case it will reflect the same value that you see in the suggestions which is the person.given_name.
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                $('.select_ingredient').val(ui.item.name);
                return false;
            },
 // Once a value in the drop down list is selected, do the following:
            select: function(event, ui) {
 // place the person.given_name value into the textfield called 'select_origin'...
                $('.select_ingredient').val(ui.item.name);
 // and place the person.id into the hidden textfield called 'link_origin_id'.
        $('.link_ingredient_id').val(ui.item.id);
                return false;
            }
        })
 // The below code is straight from the jQuery example. It formats what data is displayed in the dropdown box, and can be customized.
        .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
 // For now which just want to show the person.name in the list.
                .append( "<a>" + item.name + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };
    });
    </script>


<div class="ingredientsForm" id="new_ingredients_form">
  <%= label_tag "ingredients" %>
  <input class="select_ingredient"/>
  <input class="link_ingredient_id" name="link[ingredient_id]" type="hidden"/>
  <%= label_tag "servings" %>
  <%= text_field_tag "servings[]" %>
</div>
```

ingredients_controller.rb

```
class IngredientsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    if params[:term]
      @ingredients = Ingredient.find(:all,:conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "#{params[:term]}%"])
    else
      @ingredients = Ingredient.all
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @ingredients.to_json }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it by using `$(document).on("keydown.autocomplete",".select_ingredient",function(e){}`

Fully revised function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(document).on("keydown.autocomplete",".select_ingredient",function(e){
$(this).autocomplete({
         minLength: 2,
        source: '<%= ingredients_path(:json) %>',
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.name);
            return false;
        },
         select: function(event, ui) {
             $(this).val(ui.item.name);
     $('.link_ingredient_id').val(ui.item.id);
            return false;
        }
    })
     .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
             .append( "<a>" + item.name + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you did it finally..  :D

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#addNewIngredient").on('click', function(){
  e.preventDefault();
$("#ingredientField").append($("#new_ingredients_form").html());
});

$("#removeIngredient").on('click', function(){
  e.preventDefault();
$("#ingredientField #new_ingredients_form").empty();
});
});
```

See the first answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682241/jquery-not-working-processing-instruction-not-closed)

Other thing you can do is: write your jquery code in a function(say applyJquery() ) and write 
`href="#" onclick="applyJquery();`  or `href="javascript:applyJquery();`

Jquery often does not works with dynamically created elements the way it works with static ones.

Use `.on()` see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380864/jquery-not-working-in-dynamically-generated-form)

EDIT: write:  $(document).on("event",".class",function(e){     $(this).autocomplete({      //write something     });

Comment: bdw why are you using `href="javascript:;"` why not use `href='#'` ?

Comment: That didn't work. Does it have something to do with the href="javascript:;" in the link? <a href="javascript:;" class="addNewIngredient">Add ingredient</a>

Comment: Ha! A few seconds late there on my part. Let me try that now.

Comment: Just switched it to href='#' and it still didn't work :(

Comment: OK, I'll try that. I forgot to mention that there was a small error in that the function doesn't have "e" being passed in. However, I added that and it still didn't work.

Comment: hey are you using  Jquery validation plug-in?

Comment: Used the code in your revised answer and it's still not working. No, I'm not using the validation plug-in

Comment: to apply jquery on dynamic elements use `.on()` see the edited answer

Comment: Yup, I'm using .on() Still no luck... Do I need to modify the autocomplete function(s) as well to use .on()? If so, where?

Comment: yes , write:  `$(document).on("event",".class",function(e){
    $(this).autocomplete({
     //write something
    }); `

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as to how to rewrite this. I have the original autocomplete function in my question. Would you be able to modify your answer to use .on()? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: pleased to know that you got it fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$('form').on('click', '#addNewIngredient', function() {...
```

however duplicate ID's are invalid html, so you should use a classname instead of the id attribute e.g.

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="addNewIngredient">Add ingredient</a>
```

and

```
$('form').on('click', '.addNewIngredient', function() {...
```

Comment: I changed all the id's to classes, tried the suggested code and it's still not working. Any thoughts on what else I could try?

Comment: I did some changes but it's still not working. I updated the question.